# ofstream flushing file to disk before watchdog timeout

Tags: c++, flush, ofstream, watchdog

I write to a file every second using ofstream. However there is a chance a watchdog timer might trigger, causing my entire system to reset. When this happens I am losing all of my data I wrote to the file. I tried std:flush, disabling buffers with myfile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0,0), and tried myfile.flush() before myfile.close(). Nothing seems to work. Any suggestions? This is in C++.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible using anything specific with ofstream. So what I did was call fsync() on the file after I closed it, and this solved the problem.